# How to make golang standardize unicode strings that have multiple ways to be encoded?

Tags: go, unicode

It is possible to encode a unicode character in multiple different ways. This is annoying when creating software. For example, the following string can be encoded with two different rune sequences:

```
νῦν: 957 965 834 957 
νῦν: 957 8166 957
```

Is there a function in golang that can stand standardize into one method of encoding? I assume something like mashing 965 834 into 8166.

Sample code for anyone interested in this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    //r1 := "νῦν"
    //r2 := "νῦν"
    r1 := []rune{957, 965, 834, 957}
    r2 := []rune{957, 8166, 957}


    fmt.Printf("%s %d: ", string(r1), len(r1))
    for i := 0; i < len(r1); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%d ", r1[i])
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n")

    fmt.Printf("%s %d: ", string(r2), len(r2))
    for i := 0; i < len(r2); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%d ", r2[i])
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n")
}
```

Comment: This is a rather general problem with Unicode, and occurs in German and French as well for instance. Normalization is the usual answer, but of course there are multiple normalized forms. Yikes!

Comment: You might be interested in https://blog.golang.org/normalization. Basically reading all the blog posts there is beneficial.

Comment: Nitpick: These are not different "encodings" of the string (both are UTF-8) but different "representations".

Comment: This post is being discussed on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406540).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm` package can be used:

```
func fixUnicode(in string) string {
    return norm.NFC.String(in)
}
```